# Логирование ошибок на сервере Debian 8

Tags: linux, node.js, debian, pm2

Есть тестовый сервер на `NodeJs`, никакое логирование не прикручивал. Иногда вылетает.  Автоматическое поднятие обеспечивается `pm2` Можно ли как-то посмотреть какую ошибку выкидывает?

Comment: Сервис вообще ничего не выхлопывает ни в stdot ни в stder? Что из этого у вас: systemd/upstart/sysv-init и т.д, какая версия Debian? С таким описанием в вопроса, получить ответ крайне проблематично - причина нет конкретики.

Comment: @Hellseher, спасибо за критику). Такое описание из-за того, что я пользователь Windows. Надеялся на ответ типа: "введи  команду такую-то". Сервер `Debian 8`. Upstart мне заменяет `pm2` (если я правильно понимаю, что такое upstart). Что такое `stdot/stder` не знаю.

Comment: Память сильно забита? `free -m`. Что дает `grep "Killed process" /var/log/syslog`

Comment: `Upstart мне заменяет pm2 ... Что такое stdot/stder не знаю. `. Вы как скрипт запускаете? `pm2 ...`? Тогда `pm2 logs` - там ищите свою ошибку. `stdout/stderr` это стандартный вывод и вывод ошибок, по умолчанию вывод в консоль.

Comment: @TotalPusher, благодарю - `pm2` мне действительно помог узнать какая ошибка вылетала. Можете оформить как ответ